# Google Chrome adding in unwanted <br>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm marking up a page using bootstrap. The content is loaded in dynamically with ajax requests and then inserted into the #content element. The particular page in question mostly contains paragraphs, headings, blockquotes and some youtube/soundcloud embeds. The problem I have is that in-between EVERY single element a line-break `<br>` is inserted when I load the page in Google Chrome. This makes it look oddly spaced out and has unwanted effects on the layout. If I load this page up in IE it looks exactly as intended (that's a first) and the line breaks are not being added in.

[The page in question](http://bassartnetwork.com/#/post/10006)

Edit: The only solution I have thought of so far is styling the `<br>` tag to not take up any space at all but then that kinda defeats the point of it.

Edit #2: Here is a screen shot to demonstrate.
[image: Example]

Edit #3: On further inspection this now appears to be happening on IE too. The problem is not isolated to Chrome. Below is the code I used to fetch the content dynamically:

```
function load(url) {
    $('#content').html("");
    $('#loader').show();
    $.get('/dyn/' + url, function(data) {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#content').html(data);
        $('.navbar-nav>.active').removeClass("active");
        $('.navbar-nav>li>a[href*="' + page + '"]').parent().addClass("active");
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
    page = url.split("/")[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the javascript code you used to insert the fetched content? It's hard to reproduce your problem without knowing exactly what you've done.

Comment: Looking at the data returned by the '/dyn/' call, there are `br` tags all over the place.  This isn't happening browser-side.

Comment: You're right, I just saw that myself

Answer (score 0):

silly question, sorry. There was some server-side code causing this issue.

```
<? echo preg_replace("/\r?\n|\r/", "<br />", $review['content']); ?>
```